# Use radio button to show or hide divs in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In my **Vue 3.0.5 app**, I want to switch between `<div>` elements by radio buttons, i.e. only show one element at a time. It works if I prefix the `value` argument in the input element with `v-bind` although I am already assign the value with `v-model`. However, I don't understand why.

I have also used radio buttons to select for ascending/descending order (I implemented a `computed` function for sorting which used the variable for asc/desc): This worked without `v-bind`.

It's not clear to me why the behaviour is different. Can anyone explain?

**Example with `v-bind`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.5"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div>
        <label><input type="radio" v-model="showFirst" v-bind:value="true" checked />First View</label>
        <br />
        <label><input type="radio" v-model="showFirst" v-bind:value="false" />Second View</label>
      </div>
      {{ showFirst }}

      <div v-if="showFirst">First view</div>
      <div v-else>Second view</div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var app = Vue.createApp({
        data() {
          return {
            showFirst: true,
          };
        },
      });

      app.mount("#app");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Example without `v-bind`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.5"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div>
        <label><input type="radio" v-model="showFirst" value="true" checked />First View</label>
        <br />
        <label><input type="radio" v-model="showFirst" value="false" />Second View</label>
      </div>
      {{ showFirst }}

      <div v-if="showFirst">First view</div>
      <div v-else>Second view</div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var app = Vue.createApp({
        data() {
          return {
            showFirst: true,
          };
        },
      });

      app.mount("#app");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `value="true"` evaluates `"true"` as a string. `:value="true"` evaluates `true` as boolean. The `:` prefix is a shorthand for `v-bind:` which evaluates the expression as JavaScript. In other words, `value="true"` is equivalent with `:value="'true'"` and it's not what you want. You want `:value="true"`. Note all the quotes in detail. Everything else in your example is correct (except `checked`, which is redundant - it will be checked based on the model value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that you're not binding the value, it is that the value is not set as a boolean. If you use `v-bind` then it gets converted to a boolean.

So you **should** use `v-bind:value="true"` (or the shorthand `:value="true")

otherwise, you could do `v-if="showFirst === 'true'"`
or, for fun, get creative with number values (input: `value="0"` and then  v-if: `Boolean(parseInt(showFirst))`

#### example

```js
  var app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        showFirst: true,
      };
    },
  });

  app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.5"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <label><input type="radio" v-model="showFirst" value="true" />First View</label
    ><br />
    <label><input type="radio" v-model="showFirst" value="false" />Second View</label>
  </div>
  {{ showFirst }}

  <div v-if="showFirst === 'true'">First view</div>
  <div v-else>Second view</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`v-model` is a two-way binding shorthand for `:modelValue=""` together with `@update:modelValue=""`. In Vue 2, it used to be `:value=""` and `@input=""`. You should only use either `v-model` or the other one.

When you add a property `value="true"`, it means that you are passing the string `"true"` as a value to the component. When using a colon before `value`, you pass an expression, which evaluates to a value. So, adding `:value="true"` actually passes to evaluated expression down, which is a boolean (it could also be a variable, a calculation etc.). `v-bind:` is equal to just a colon `:`, usually the short form is used.

See also the [docs to `v-model` from Vue](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html#overview).